# How to refresh the contents of the variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code that has various fields...

```
<div id="tabs-5" data-content-theme="b" data-theme="b" class="ui-body ui-body-b ui-corner-all">
  <form id="fileEn">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="files">Upload Image Files</label>
      <input id="files" type="file" data-clear-btn="true" value="" multiple/>
      <div id="progress_bar">
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
      </div>
      <output id="result1"></output>
      <output id="result2"></output>
      <output id="result3"></output>
      <output id="result4"></output>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="pwdF">Enter Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="pwdF" id="val4" value="" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="bitsF" class="select">Choose bits:
      </label>
      <select name="bitsF" id="val5">
        <option value="128">128</option>
        <option value="192">192</option>
        <option value="256">256</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="load1();return false;" value="Compute" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Here onclick of a button called 'Compute' the load1() function is called...
This load1() function does some computation and saves the computed file..eg:file1.doc...next i press the 'reset' button to get empty fields...now when i press the 'Compute' button again,the current computed file eg:file2.doc as well as the previous computed file(file1.doc) are saved..this is because the previous contents were not removed..

Can anyone please suggest so as to how i can perform the action similar to Ctrl+F5 onclick of a suitable button (preferably reset button itself which inturn calls a different function inorder to refresh)to refresh the contents..so that only the current computed file is saved (file2.doc) and not all the previous ones(file1.doc)...

Comment: If you want emulate the `[CTRL] + [F5]` to refresh the page, use: `location.reload(true);`.

Comment: How do i integrate this with the reset button so that onclick of it,the tabs should be reset and refresh should occur as well..

Comment: Can anyone suggest so as to how this can be done...

Comment: I don't understand completely your question, but I've made an example. Please, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some actions when the form performs the reset action, by using:

```
var fileEn = document.getElementById("fileEn"); // Get the form identifier.
fileEn.addEventListener("reset", function() { // When the form performs the reset action.
   reset(); // Call the reset function.
});
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    function load1() {
      alert("The compute button has been pressed.");
    }

    function reset() {
      alert("The reset button has been pressed.");
      var files = document.getElementById("files");
      files.value = ""; // To reset the input file field.
    }

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      load1();
    });

    var fileEn = document.getElementById("fileEn"); // Get the form identifier.
    fileEn.addEventListener("reset", function() { // When the form performs the reset action.
      reset(); // Call the reset function.
    });
  };
})();
```

```html
<div id="tabs-5" data-content-theme="b" data-theme="b" class="ui-body ui-body-b ui-corner-all">
  <form id="fileEn">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="files">Upload Image Files</label>
      <input id="files" type="file" data-clear-btn="true" value="" multiple/>
      <div id="progress_bar">
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
      </div>
      <output id="result1"></output>
      <output id="result2"></output>
      <output id="result3"></output>
      <output id="result4"></output>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="pwdF">Enter Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="pwdF" id="val4" value="" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="bitsF" class="select">Choose bits:
      </label>
      <select name="bitsF" id="val5">
        <option value="128">128</option>
        <option value="192">192</option>
        <option value="256">256</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Compute" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" />
  </form>
</div>
```